# Google plus: No name in user profile info

Tags: android, google-plus

I have added Google+ log in in my application, and Once I have the account name, I want to get basic User profile info, this way:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo");
//get Access Token with Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE
String sAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity.this,
                        mPlusClient.getAccountName() + "",
                        "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE
                        + " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
                        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "
        + sAccessToken);
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
line = total.toString();
```

It usually gives me these details:

> "id" "email" "give_name" "family_name" "name" "link" "verified_email"
>   "gender" "locale" "picture"

But while testing I created a new Google account with `firstName` and `LastName`. And its been shown on my Google+ account.

But when I call the same API for User Info with this account name, I get:

> { "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
>   "verified_email": true, "locale": "en"}

nothing related to name.

Any work around for such cases?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google+ login, you don't want to do it slightly different. Rather than hitting the userinfo endpoint, but the Google+ profile endpoint: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get. On Android this is as simple as calling the helper method in the PlusClient in Google Play Services: mPlusClient.loadPerson(this, "me");

Using "me" as the user ID will return the profile of the currently signed in user, which includes the display name.

The scopes you have will work, but you wont need userinfo.profile, and you can change PLUS_PROFILE to PLUS_LOGIN to get access to a bit more flexibility!

Take a look at the updated sign in documentation for a more detailed example: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in and https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_profile_information

Comment: Yeah. You are right. But even after connecting(in `onConnected`) and providing all the `permissions` when I load person I get `ConnectionResult{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}` and `Person = null` in `onPersonLoaded` :(. Hence I am following this approach. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Hmm, network error does sound like there is a more fundamental problem. Would you be able to update your question with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) to register your digitally signed .apk file's public certificate in the Google APIs Console?

Comment: Yeah. Like I said in the question, everything works fine most of the time. This is the 1st time I am seeing no data related to name, for this particular account.